# How to synchronize two docker volumes?

Tags: database, docker, mariadb, devops, data-synchronization

I am working on a docker-compose project where I have a mariadb service with named volume as "test-stage-database" for stage compose project and "test-master-database" for master compose project.

My deploy workflow is to create the exact copy of master project in stage server and then pointing the master domain to stage server. So I wanted to create an exact replica of database-storage volume of master project in stage server.

So far I have tried something like

```
docker run --volumes-from=test-master.mariadb \
       -v test-stage-database:/tmp \
       --name rsync \
       --restart unless-stopped \
       rsync:alpine \
       rsync -a --info=progress2 /var/lib/mysql/ /tmp
```

But after rync the two volumes I always have to restart my stage mariadb server to see the updates.

So in general this covers two questions.

1. What is the best way to synchronize two docker volumes
2. What is the best way to synchronize Mariadb master server with stage without restarting each time data is updated.

Comment: Assuming that LVM is the secret sauce under the covers, I wonder if there is a way to use LVM to take a _snapshot_ of one docker to get the other.

Comment: I haven't heard that word before. Google results give me this link https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-devicemapper-storage-driver . Is it the same you are talking about ?

Comment: "Logical Volume Manager" -- I guess I guessed right.  (No, I don't know how to do the next step.  Maybe someone else will chime in.)